# cppyy with std::function<double(std::vector<double>) callback

Tags: python, std-function, cppyy

I am using cppyy. I want to pass a function to my C++. The C++ expects a function of signature `std::function<double(std::vector<double>)>`. I don't know how to do it. Here is a minimal example of the error:

```
import cppyy

# To be passed to C
def callback(x):
  return 10.

cppyy.cppdef("double callback_vector(const std::function<double(std::vector<double>)>& callback, std::vector<double> x) { return callback(x); }")
cppyy.cppdef("double callback(const std::function<double(double)>& callback, std::vector<double> x) { return callback(x[0]); }")

cppyy.gbl.callback(callback, [1]) # works
cppyy.gbl.callback_vector(callback, [1]) # fails
```

but I find

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cppyy.gbl.callback_vector(callback, [1])
TypeError: double ::callback_vector(function<double(std::vector<double> >& callback, vector<double> x) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
```

In other words, with `std::function<double(std::vector<double>)>` it fails, but with the simpler  `std::function<double(double)>` signature it works.

Comment: Is a parsing bug deep in the bowels of the backend. For the life of me, I can't devise a simple workaround b/c it keeps on hitting the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, the problem is deep inside the backend (a parsing bug), which mangles the `std::function` name into something unrecognizable. It does this to for a range of workarounds that I have tried.

The closest solution I can come up with is this:

```
cppyy.cppdef("""
    struct VecDArg : public std::vector<double> {
        VecDArg(const std::vector<double>& v) : std::vector<double>(v) {}
    };
    double wrap_callback_vector(const std::function<double(VecDArg)>& wrap, const std::vector<double>& x) {
        return callback_vector(wrap, x);
    }
""")

cppyy.gbl.callback_vector = cppyy.gbl.wrap_callback_vector
cppyy.gbl.callback_vector(callback, [1])
```

The reason why the above works, is that it hides the type name from the backend and thus prevents the problem with parsing. By deriving from `std::vector`, the Python class is mostly none the wiser.

**EDIT**: Now fixed in repo. Will be part of release 1.7.0. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. I used a similar trick for `std::vector<double>(std::vector<double>)` signature